# Automatically create hyperlink based on span class

Tags: navigation

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? I want my content writer to be able to add span classes to certain numerical amounts that then automatically hyperlink to a pre-defined URL. Example:

> And the price at John's hardware shop is`<span class="john-shop">`$2.35`</span>`

I am fully aware there is a module called [Word Link](https://drupal.org/project/word_link) Which does a fantastic job of hyperlinking specific keywords but as numerical amounts are not specific to anything this is a tad more challenging. What I mean by this is in Word Link you can say:

"coca cola" - link automatically to www.cocacola.com
"Nike" - link automatically to www.nike.com

"$5.67" is just a number so a span class would be approriate.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: How will the "pre-defined URL" be determined? Is it based of some value from the node? Or is something fixed for all?

Comment: I will define them myself. span class="johns" = Place a hyperlink to http://johns-shop.com. span class="sarahs" = Place a hyperlink to http://sarahs-shop.com. The information can be stored in a node though for each shop.

Comment: RichStevens We don't care if you define it yourself or if you hire a contractor ;) the meaning of @angheloko comment is probably more like "where are the assignments stored for the automata to use?". Your "tored in a node" is pretty vague.

Comment: I will store the URLs in a content type called 'shops' in a field that will contain the URL. I actually need a slight bit of guidance as to the best way of doing this. I know it's possible with jquery as a kind gentleman sent me this: http://jsfiddle.net/C7Hnf/ I just don't know how to get it running on a Drupal site.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your field-template file.

```
<?php foreach($class in $classes)): ?>
  <?php if ($class == 'johns' ): ?>
    // do something
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($class == 'sarahs' ): ?>
    // do something
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Downside this way is you need to maintain a list in the templatefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this via [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

**Via hook_node_view_alter()**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function test_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = $build['#node'];

  $pattern = '/<span class="[A-Za-z\-_ ]*">\$[0-9\.,]+<\/span>/';

  // Get the link from a field in the node.
  // This assumes field_url is a text field that contains the URL
  // (e.g. http://http://drupal.stackexchange.com).
  $replacement_link = $node->field_url[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

  // Get the subject.
  // This assumes that the text you want to replace is in the 'body' field.
  $string = $build['body'][0]['#markup'];
  $build['body'][0]['#markup'] = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='".$replacement_link."'>$0</a>", $string);
}
```

There are downsides to this approach:

1. You have to make sure that the author adheres to the pattern (`<span class="<SOME-CLASS>">$<NUMERICAL-VALUE></span>`). Any deviation from the pattern may result to text not being replaced.
2. This will replace all instances that matches the pattern.
3. The preferred way to manipulate DOM via PHP is by using HTML DOM Parsers.